# How do I update this query so as to use listagg instead of wm_concat?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, csv, listagg

I have a query that looks like this which I inherited from another developer, this is its select statement

```
select distinct 
    wm_concat(
        nvl(
            listagg(USER_CODE,',') within group (order by USER_CODE),
            USER_CODE
        )
    )
```

How can I update this to work using listagg?

I understand what listagg does and how it operates, but I'm not sure what the outcome of wrapping this nvl-wrapped listagg in wm_concat was to begin with, and since we're on 12c now, I can't test what their old output was supposed to look like.

Comment: show us the full code!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WM_CONCAT()` is an undocumented Oracle function, that does pretty much the same thing as `LISTAGG()`, and whose usage is discouraged. Since it is not officially supported, it may break anytime when you upgrade.

You did not show the whole query so is still to be confirmed, but:

- I do not see the logic of using `WM_CONCAT()` as a wrapper around `LISTAGG()`
- the use of `NVL(LISTAGG(user_code ...) ..., user_code)` does not seem to make sense: `LISTAGG()` is an aggregate function, so using it implies that column `user_code` is aggregated. Since this column is aggregated, you cannot use it a second argument to `NVL()`...

Bottom line, I would simply suggest to drop all that fancy (and probably invalid) stuff and use a simple aggregate expression:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(user_code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_code) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`WM_CONCAT(some_field)` is essentially the same thing as `LISTAGG(some_field, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY some_field)`, so since `LISTAGG(...)` returns a single value the `WM_CONCAT` is effectively a no-op. Eliminate it from your query and move on.